# jQuery breaks if function does not exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

Tinymce stops working if on the same page I use the selectmenu from https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui

Tinymce with default configuration

and selectmenu:

```
$('select.flags').selectmenu();
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that on the page with tinymce i dont load the script for the `selectmenu` function. Should I remove it from the js that runs all the functions or is there any way to modify it to run only if the function exists and will be able to be ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to make 'function does not exist' problems go away.

```
 $.fn.selectmenu = $.fn.selectmenu || $.noop
 $('select.jquery_smenu').selectmenu(); //do what you will
```

or you could do it like this:

```
if( $.fn.selectmenu ){
   $('select.jquery_smenu').selectmenu(); //do what you will
}
```

for the record, function does not exist or var is not a function is a javascript problem more than a jQuery one. Hope this helps!

Comment: `$().selectmenu` should be `$.fn.selectmenu`.

Comment: You can read `$().selectmenu`, but when you want to set a property on the jQuery prototype it's `$.fn.selectmenu`.  (`$.prototype === $.fn`)

Answer (score 2):

Is tiny working with this script added to the page, but not initialized for the selects?

You apply selectmenu to every single select on your page.
tinymce uses selects and your surely don't want to change these.

Give your selects a class like

```
<select class="jquery_smenu"> ....
```

and change your selector:

```
$('select.jquery_smenu').selectmenu();
```

I can not test if thats the reason why tiny stops working, but you should change that.

Comment: Constantin: is it (tinymce) working without initializing selectmenu (remove the jQuery line you just changed)

Comment: yes, it is working properly but adding the selectmenu function makes the tinymce stop working and still the selectmenu works